# How to load array of data into dataset format using React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In my-scenario, I am trying to restructure the array before loading into line chart. Here,I am receiving props like: `const data = [26.727, 26.952, 12.132, 25.933, 12.151, 28.492, 12.134, 26.191]`

I want to restructure the data like below, before loading into line chart

```
   const dataTwo = [

{
          value: 26.727,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },
        {
          value: 26.952,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },
       {
          value: 12.132,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },,
        {
          value: 25.933,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },
        {
          value: 12.151,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },
        {
          value: 28.492,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },,
        {
          value: 12.134,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.RED,
          },
        },
        {
          value: 12.134,
          svg: {
            fill: Colors.WHITE,
          },
        },
```

The array of last before index, I need to insert unique colour value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COnsider this example:

```js
enum Colors {
    WHITE = 'white',
    RED = 'red'
}
const data = [26.727, 26.952, 12.132, 25.933, 12.151, 28.492, 12.134, 26.191]

const DEFAULT_SVG = {
    fill: Colors.WHITE,
}


const makeElem = (value: number) => ({ value, svg: DEFAULT_SVG })

const applySvg = (value: { value: number, svg: { fill: Colors } }, index: number) => index === 6 ? {
    ...value,
    svg: {
        fill: Colors.RED,
    }
} : value
const predicate = (elem: number, index: number) => applySvg(makeElem(elem), index)

const builder = (props: number[]) =>
    props.map(predicate)

const result = builder(data)
```

Just pass your props to `builder` function

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QN4Cgq6gdQAkBJAFQFEoBeKAcgHcALASwBdhaAaHPAJXIAi1OsmAATWlgC%20WAMZwQqVlDEBDVquEBtAEwA2AHQB2HUc5R9BgJwBWHeYCMOgw4DM9izeuvXj5w5sHcx0ADgMAFisPJxdXcODDBysHAF0sOQUlKAFyADEAQQBVABlSAH0AZQA1AHFhbDwoADNmBAQALlhEFFQDIjJybhl0%20UVlCFUAa2ByBGBoGgAKADdVBDBgTvAIACNgZABKagA%20KEWMKFX14HNUZYBzTpyCkvLquqkDkczlVQAHP4IACeFQewhWaw2nQuVyhUG2e2Qtwe0OarQ6XSQaCgUhx5mYIDEwAAHltIIijlRTgSicTqFQaHooAB%20TA8XAGTmwm7sqB3R5sxqNFptTrwLG9fgCbiNGS4zrcjJjKB-URiZiydTAcHAOYQMm7fb4wkkg0Uk5Qf6AkEPRYTaazeaLXXzA7G2lfJVZHZgVpE5Dg1VwP6oM37LQpSnHXlBkMGCZ-Raq8QarWe0ZZUSoMAIZQ0H1%20-aLNQaA5AA)

Comment: thank you. btw again need to use dataSet hardcode? Actually this dataSet array formation inside props.data I loaded manually by index value, instead of that it the dataset value should load based on props.data count and it will fetch all the values into dataSet array.

Comment: SOrry, I just forgot to remove hardcoded array. Made an update

Comment: please share exact example how do you call it. because it works in playground

Comment: no problem. all value : 0 it is loading but data format is very good. const builder = (dataSet: any[] )=> {
    var finalData = new Array(dataSet.length)
    .fill(0)
    .map(predicate) 
    console.log("DATA***********************:",finalData)
    return finalData;
  }

Comment: Above solution not working. Data is coming empty but in the passing props data is there.

Comment: @RNDev please share exact code that you are using, but please share it in ts playground instead of comments

Comment: I have updated my question and code. Please check it.